# (b) List the resources that made a statue. - SPARQL on protege

Tags: sparql

`enter code here`    RDF schema:
`enter code here`   <rdf:RDF xml:base="http://art.org/">
`enter code here`   <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Bacchus">
`enter code here`    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#statue"/>
`enter code here`   art:titleBacchus</art:title>
`enter code here`  art:value2000000</art:value>
`enter code here`</rdf:Description>
`enter code here` <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Deluge">
`enter code here`<krdf:type rdf:resource="#painting"/>
`enter code here`amkrt:titleThe Deluge</art:title>
`enter code here`art:value3000000</art:value>
`enter code here`</rdf:Description>
`enter code here`<rdf:Description rdf:about="#Madonna">
`enter code here`<rdf:type rdf:resource="#painting"/>
`enter code here`art:titleMadonna of the Pinks</art:title>
`enter code here`art:value4000000</art:value>
`enter code here`</rdf:Description>
`enter code here`<rdfs:Class rdf:about="#painting"/>
`enter code here` <rdfs:Class rdf:about="#statue"/>
`enter code here`<art:painter rdf:about="#Michelangelo">
`enter code here`<art:made rdf:resource="#Deluge"/>
`enter code here`<art:made rdf:resource="#Bacchus"/>
`enter code here`<rdf:type rdf:resource="#sculptor"/>
`enter code here`</art:painter>
`enter code here`<art:painter rdf:about="#Raphael">
`enter code here`<art:made rdf:resource="#Madonna"/>
`enter code here`</art:painter>
`enter code here`</rdf:RDF>

Comment: please edit your question, you should see that this can't be the correct formatting

Comment: also, what did you try so far with SPARQL - this is not a platform for requesting queries without any effort, any SPARQL tutorial should at least bring you to some starting query - especially given that you request is basically rather simple such that you should be able to write such a query once you had a look at some SPARQL tutorial